# How can I make a button take up its entire containing form?

Tags: c#, button

I've made a floating button. I want it to take up the whole of the it's containing form but the below code has a margin between the right of the button and the right of the form.

```
   public FloatButton()
   {
        InitializeComponents();
        int width = (int)((double)Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width / 20);
        int height = (int)((double)Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 20);
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        int x_pos = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width - width; 
        int y_pos = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height / 2 - height / 2;
        this.Location = new Point(x_pos,y_pos);
        this.Height = height;
        this.Width = width;
        this.button.Width = width;
        this.button.Height = height;
    }
```

EDIT: It's about 40 pixels and it doesn't change if I make the button text longer (the text wraps)

Comment: How big a gap? Does the size of the gap change with the contents of the button?

Comment: Try to place it in a Panel and dock it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does docking work for you?

```
 this.button.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
```

Just setting Dock to Fill should make the button fill up its parent's entire area.

Comment: this works (the button fills up the form). Any explanation as to why it doesn't work by simply setting the size?